# .netcore 6.0 Querystring length causing badrequest

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, query-string, bad-request, maxlength

having issue when i am passing  2048 bit encrypted string (very long set of characters) in Querystring and keep getting bad request.
I tried the following
requestlimits in web.config - doesnt work
configure Kestrel options - MaxRequestLineSize - it works only if the application is started as exe but does not work when launched with IISExpress or IIS - both out of process and in process.
Configure in startup - MaxRequestBodySize

Following is my web.config as requested

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <security>
        <requestFiltering >
          <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" maxUrl="2147483647" maxQueryString="2147483647" />
        </requestFiltering>
      </security>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\ACServicesIntegrationAPI.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime  maxUrlLength="40960" maxQueryStringLength="2097151" maxRequestLength="40960" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

tried this as well

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    
                   
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                    webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel((context, options) =>
                    {
                        options.Limits.MaxRequestLineSize = 32768;
                    });
                    
                });
```

Any ideas/solution?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Could you please inform us, what is the length of your query string? I would suggest you keep the query string limit high than the actual length of the query string. For example, set the limit to 5000 if the query string length is about 4500. You could specify this limit in the `web.config` file in `requestFiltering` tag using this line of code. `<requestLimits maxQueryString="8192" />`

Comment: i alread have this in my web.config. it is still not accepting. Added the config to the question.

Comment: I would suggest you try to configure Failed request tracing rule in the IIS. After reproducing the issue. Try to check the Failed request tracing logs and see whether you get any helpful information there to narrow down the issue.